# Can GPO grey out (not disable) "Enable Javascript" option?

Tags: group-policy, adobe, adobe-reader, adobe-acrobat

I understand GPO can be used to disable or enable "Enable Javascript" option in Acrobat Reader.  However, is there a way we can **grey** it out so that user cannot fiddle with it? 
Thanks in advance.